# .htaccess not working properly(css not working)

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to apply rewrite rules on my Web Page But When i try below code 
then all external stylesheets not works e.g bootstrap

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^download/(.*).html$ search.php?q=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is that the *only* rewrite rule you have in either the `.htaccess` or the main virtual host file?

Comment: It's because you are linking with relative URL's. Either change your style link to use a leading slash in the href like this `<link .... href="/path/to/style.css">` or add `<base href="/" >` to the head section of your html.